# Wordpress how to display ACF Image field from user profile

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, user-profile

I am having trouble displaying an ACF image field. You can see how the field is setup in the attached screenshot. I am using the code below in a template file to display the various fields from the Authors role only:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'role'    => 'Author',
    'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users( $args );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $users as $user ) {

    echo $user->display_name . '<br>';
    echo $user->title . '<br>';
    echo $user->short_bio . '<br>';
    echo $user->full_bio . '<br>';
    echo $user->author_photo . '<br>';

}
echo '</ul>';

?>
```

You can see the author_photo field at the end, but it is only returning a number value, not the image url, even the return format of the field is set to Image URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to get the `ACF field` for a specific user in a different way than you've already tried.

> The id should contain the word ‘user_’ and the user’s ID in the format; "user_{$user_id}".
> [From ACF <sup>*Docs*</sup>](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/)

```php
$args = array(
  'role'    => 'Author',
  'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
  'order'   => 'ASC'
);

$users = get_users( $args );

echo '<ul>';

foreach ( $users as $user ) {

  $author_array_img = get_field('author_photo', 'user_' . $user->ID);
  echo $user->display_name . '<br>';
  echo $user->title . '<br>';
  echo $user->short_bio . '<br>';
  echo $user->full_bio . '<br>';
  echo $author_array_img['sizes']['thumbnail'] . '<br>';

}
echo '</ul>';
```

Let me know if you were able to get it to work!

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you so much. I follow what you did in the code, makes total sense.

Comment: This works beautifully! Thank you so much.